# Compiling erlang with systemtap but require dtrace

Tags: linux, erlang, dtrace, systemtap

I'm compiling erlang otp from source like following:

```
./configure --with-dynamic-trace=systemtap
```

But it reports error:

```
checking for dtrace... no
configure: error: No dtrace utility found.
```

I think systemtap is for linux usage and it is different from dtrace, am I right?

---

After installed [dtrace](ftp://crisp.dyndns-server.com/pub/release/website/dtrace) Now the error is:

```
dtrace: failed to compile script emulator/beam/erlang_dtrace.d: Preprocessor not found
configure: error: Could not precompile erlang_dtrace.d: dtrace -h failed
configure: error: /root/otp/erts/configure failed for erts
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which distro are you using? I'd forget using DTRACE, it will be a bit harder to make it to work than Systemtap (at least it was for me). I'm using Systemtap and it works perfectly.

If you are not using Fedora/RH you should patch your kernel with UTRACE or use a kernel >= 3.5 with UPBOBES enabled.

To verify if your kernel has UTRACE/UPROBE enabled run this:

```
grep UTRACE /boot/config-$(uname -r)
```

or

```
grep PROBES /boot/config-$(uname -r)
```

For example, in my machine (Ubuntu 12.04 with Mainline kernel 3.5):

```
$ grep UTRACE /boot/config-$(uname -r)
$
$ grep UPROBES /boot/config-$(uname -r)
CONFIG_ARCH_SUPPORTS_UPROBES=y
CONFIG_UPROBES=y
```

You should also have systemtap installed. The version shipped with Ubuntu (my case) is quite old, so I compiled it from source (traditional configure/make/make install). You can get it here:

http://sourceware.org/systemtap/ftp/releases/

I'm using version 1.8.

Then try to recompile it again. It should work.

Regards

Comment: Thank you, I prefer systemtap too. My distro is Fedora17. `rep UTRACE /boot/config-$(uname -r)` get `CONFIG_UTRACE=y`. Systemtap is 1.8. It is very strange that it requires dtrace while I chose systemtap as the trace tool when configure erlang.

Comment: It's ok now. I installed systemtap from source and it's ok. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

- After installing systemtap(sudo apt-get install systemtap), exiting or logging out from the current shell session then logging in may help.
- Also, you may try using [kerl](https://github.com/kerl/kerl).